# How can I parallelize my code about deleting overlapping spheres?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a piece of code. What my code does is checking if some spheres (defined by their coordinates xcentro, ycentro, zcentro and their radii r) overlapp each other or not. If they overlap, I must delete them, but as I don't know how to delete a component of a vector (it's a mess with the index and stuff) I just set the radii to zero and do not take them into account later.

My problem comes when I try to parallelize the code. If I don't do it, it works properly (although the code is not efficient at all and I need to run it with millions of spheres). And if I try to parallelize it, I obtain several errors. For example, if I try to run the code the exact way it is written below, I obtain segmentation fault. If I eliminate the private(...) part, I don't obtain any error, but don't obtain the same results as without parallelization.

What can I be doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, r;
r.reserve(34000000);
xcentro.reserve(34000000);
ycentro.reserve(34000000);
zcentro.reserve(34000000);
... read files and fill up xcentro ycentro zcentro r with data ...
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, d) shared(r)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size() - 1; i++)
    {

        //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, d) shared(r)
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < r.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            auto dist_square = (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j])
                             + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j])
                             + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]);
            if ( dist_square < (r[i]+r[j])*(r[i]+r[j]) )
            {
                //hacer 0 el radio de la esfera j-esima
                r[j] = 0;
                    
                //hacer 0 el radio de la esfera i-esima
                r[i] = 0;                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The result of your algorithm depends on the order of the spheres and hence the order in which they are processed. Parallelizing this (such that the result is identical to your serial algorithm) is (next to) impossible. 
But perhaps you didn't intend this to be the case?

Comment: As a simple example, consider 3 spheres that all overlap each other. Then your algorithm will delete the first two and keep the 3rd. Is this what you want?

Comment: Btw, you can limit the loops to those spheres which have `r[i]>0` and `r[j]>0`, respectively. That avoids all spheres already deleted.

Comment: @Walter you're completely right and my algorithm fails in this part, but I don't know other way to delete overlapping spheres.

Comment: Please specify the purpose of the algorithm, given a set of spheres. Shall it return all spheres that have no overlap with any other sphere? (Your present algorithm doesn't do that, as my example shows.)

Comment: @Walter the purpose is to obtain all the spheres that doesn't overlapp with any sphere. The ones that overlaps have radius zero and later, when I write the non-overlapping spheres to a file, I will ignore those with radius zero

Comment: I suggest writing an algorithm that doesn’t modify any spheres; rather it just sets a bit corresponding to a sphere when it detects that the sphere is overlapping.  Then at the end of the algorithm, iterate over the bits to see which spheres still have their bits unset.  That way your results won’t depend on the order of testing.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
    {
        overlaps[i] = 0;
        contador=0;
        //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:cuenta)
        for (j = i + 1; j < r.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j])*(xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j]))
                {
                    contador++;
                }
        }
        overlaps[i] = contador;

    }

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what about the comment I've just post and then making zero the radius of those spheres with overlaps[i]!=0 ?

Comment: You don’t need to parallelize your code; you just need to make it more efficient. Use a sweep-and-prune algorithm or construct something like a kD tree or octree for accelerating the overlap queries.

Comment: @elenafer I see two problems with setting the radius equal to zero:  the first is that if sphere A overlaps both B and C, and you detect that A overlaps B and set both of those radii to zero, then later when you look at C you won't have any way to know that it previously overlapped A and B, and therefore you may incorrectly fail to identify it as an overlapping sphere.   And second, more generally, if you want to parallelize, it's better to thread the input-data as immutable, so that you don't have to serialize access to it.  Setting radii to zero means you are modifying your input data.

Comment: As already suggested you should use a better algorithm first. Can you provide some details about the distribution of x,y,z,r values (minimum, maximum, average, mean)? How many spheres removed in a typical run?

Comment: @Sneftel I'm new in C++, any help of how doing this?

Comment: I’ve given you keywords to use for your research: “sweep and prune”, “kD-tree”, “octree”. None of them are specific to C++. They’re algorithms and data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's first consider an algorithm which actually works, i.e. obtain the subset of spheres with no overlap. To this end, we don't remove a sphere (before checking whether it overlaps with another one) but merely record that is has overlaps.

```
struct sphere { double R,X,Y,Z; };

inline constexpr double square(double x) noexcept
{ return x*x; }

inline constexpr bool overlap(sphere const&a, sphere const&b) noexcept
{ return square(a.X-b.X)+square(a.Y-b.Y)+square(a.Z-b.Z) > square(a.R+b.R); }

std::vector<sphere> keep_non_overlapping(std::vector<sphere> const&S)
{
    std::vector<char> hasOverlap(Spheres.size(), char(0));
    vector<sphere> result;
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) {
        for(size_t j=i+1; j<S.size(); ++j)
            if((!hasOverlap[i] || !hasOverlap[j]) && overlap(S[i],S[j])) {
                hasOverlap[i] = 1;
                hasOverlap[j] = 1;
            }
        if(!hasOverlap[i])
            result.push_back(S[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This algorithm loops every pair of spheres once. Since the test between spheres `k` and `l` is done when `i` equals the smaller of `k` and `l` and `j` the larger, the executions of the loop over `i` are still not mutually independent: there is still a race condition. This can be removed by looping over each pair of spheres twice:

```
std::vector<sphere> keep_non_overlapping(std::vector<sphere> const&S)
{
    std::vector<char> hasOverlap(Spheres.size(), char(0));

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) {
        bool overlapping = false;
        for(size_t j=0; !overlapping && j<S.size(); ++j)
            if(j!=i && overlap(S[i],S[j])
                overlapping = true;
        hasOverlap[i] = !overlapping;
    }

    vector<sphere> result;
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i)
        if(!hasOverlap[i])
            result.push_back(S[i]); 
    return result;
}
```

Note also that, depending on the distribution of spheres, it can make the execution significantly faster if you first order the sphere is descending radius (largest spheres first) as in

```
std::sort(S.begin(), S.end(), [](sphere const&a, sphere const&b) { return a.R > b.R; });
```

Note further that this naive O(N^2) algorithm is not optimal. There is likely a O(N ln(N)) algorithm which first arranges the spheres in some data structure (perhaps a spatial tree) in O(N ln(N)) time and then finds whether a sphere is overlapping in no more than O(ln N) time for each sphere.

Comment: what about this code? for (i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) { overlaps[i] = 0; contador=0; //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:cuenta) for (j = i + 1; j < r.size(); ++j) { if (((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j])*(xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j])) { contador++; } } overlaps[i] = contador; } and then making zero the radius of those spheres whose overlaps[i]!=0

Comment: cannot read this code in a comment like that. use markup or post another question. But it seems very similar to the first one in my answer, i.e. it's not parallelisable and will fail.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) { overlaps[i] = 0; contador=0; //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:cuenta) for (j = i + 1; j < r.size(); ++j) { if (((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j])*(xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j])) { contador++; } } overlaps[i] = contador; `

Comment: don't know how to make a new line, but basically the code checks if a sphere overlaps with other and if it does it increases vector overlaps. Finally, I do another loop and make zero the radius of those spheres whose vector overlaps is different to zero

Comment: it's quite different to your first question, and I've already checked it and this one CAN be parallelized

Comment: "there is still a race condition. This can be removed by looping over each pair of spheres twice" Why don't you use atomic operations? The code will be faster if you loop over pairs only once (and use atomic read and write)...

Answer (score 1):

Hereby, I answer your question asked in the comment:

> How could I increase the speed of my program?

The best is to completely change the algorithm (as already suggested), but if you do not wish to change it for any reason, you can gain ca. 20% speed by parallelizing the outer loop:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, r.size()/500)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
        { 
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < r.size(); ++j)
            {                
                if ((((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j])))
                {
                    #pragma omp atomic write
                    overlaps[i] = 1;
                    #pragma omp atomic write
                    overlaps[j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:
Based on @Walter’s response and code, I created a simple algorithm that is significantly faster than your code. The basic idea is as follows: Sort the data according to `x` values and determine the largest radius. For a given `x` value, it is not necessary to go through the entire range, it is enough to examine those `x` values that are closer than twice the largest radius. Thus, the number of loop cycles can be significantly reduced and the speed of the algorithm was increased by orders of magnitude. I tested the speed difference between your code and the new algorithm with the code below using arrays filled with data of randomly created spheres. I created the algorithm so that you don't have to change the rest of your program, the `new_algorithm` function takes the data from `xcentro, ycentro, zcetro, r` arrays and returns the indexes of the overlapping spheres in the `overlay2` array. On [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o7ddTz8Y9) significant speed increase was observed:

```
size=20000
Runtime(your method)=1216 ms
Runtime(new algorithm)=13 ms
```

Note that this is a simple algorithm and easy to understand how it works, but based on your real data better algorithms may be created. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

constexpr size_t N=10000;
std::vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, r;

struct sphere { double X,Y,Z,R; size_t index; };
std::vector<sphere> Spheres;

inline constexpr double square(double x) noexcept
{ return x*x; }

inline constexpr bool overlap(sphere const&a, sphere const&b) noexcept
{ return square(a.X-b.X)+square(a.Y-b.Y)+square(a.Z-b.Z) < square(a.R+b.R); }


void new_algorithm(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y, const std::vector<double>& z, const std::vector<double>& r, std::vector<char>& overlaps)
{
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    std::vector<sphere> S;
    S.reserve(r.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {
        S.push_back(sphere{x[i],y[i],z[i],r[i], i});
    }
    
    //Sort ascending X
    std::sort(S.begin(), S.end(), [](sphere const&a, sphere const&b) { return a.X < b.X; });

    
    // Clear overlaps and determine maximum r value
    double maxr=-1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
    {   
        overlaps[i]=0;
        if(S[i].R>maxr) maxr=S[i].R;
    }
    
    //Create a vector for maximum indices
    std::vector<size_t> max_index(S.size(),0);
    
    //Determine maximum_index
    size_t j=1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
    {   
        while(S[j].X-S[i].X<2*maxr)                 
        {
            if(j<r.size()) j++; else break;
        }
        max_index[i]=j;         
    }
        
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) 
    {
        for(size_t j=i+1; j<max_index[i]; ++j)
            if(overlap(S[i],S[j])) 
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                overlaps[S[i].index] = 1;
                #pragma omp atomic write
                overlaps[S[j].index] = 1;
            }
    }

    const auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Runtime(new algorithm)=" << diff.count() << " ms\n";  
}


void your_algorithm(std::vector<char>& overlaps)
{
    size_t i,j;

    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
    {
        overlaps[i]=0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {   
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (j = i + 1; j < r.size(); j++)
        {
                if ((((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j])))
                {
                    overlaps[i] = 1;
                    overlaps[j] = 1;
                }
        }
    }

    const auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Runtime(your method)=" << diff.count() << " ms" << std::endl;

}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> overlaps1, overlaps2;
    r.reserve(N);
    xcentro.reserve(N);
    ycentro.reserve(N);
    zcentro.reserve(N);
    overlaps1.reserve(N);   
    overlaps2.reserve(N);   

    //fill the arrays with random numbers
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        double x=(rand() % 1000)/10.0;
        double y=(rand() % 1000)/10.0;
        double z=(rand() % 1000)/10.0;
        double R=(rand() % 10000)/((double)N ) + 0.1;
        xcentro.push_back( x );
        ycentro.push_back( y );
        zcentro.push_back( z );
        r.push_back(R);
    }

    std::cout << "size=" << r.size() << std::endl;

    your_algorithm(overlaps1);
    new_algorithm(xcentro,ycentro,zcentro,r,overlaps2);
    
    // Check if array of overlap is the same for the 2 methods
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(overlaps1[i]!=overlaps2[i])
        {
            cout << "error\n"; exit (-1);
        }
    }   
    cout << "OK\n"; 
}
```

UPDATE2: Here is the code mentioned in comment (sort by R and remove the bigger sphere only)

```
    std::vector<sphere> S;
    S.reserve(r.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {
        overlaps[i]=0;
        S.push_back(sphere{x[i],y[i],z[i],r[i], i});
    }
    
    //Sort descending R
    std::sort(S.begin(), S.end(), [](sphere const&a, sphere const&b) { return a.R > b.R; });
            
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) 
    {
        for(size_t j=i+1; j<S.size(); ++j)
            if(overlap(S[i],S[j])) 
            {
                overlaps[S[i].index] = 1;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I've run both codes (yours and mine) several times and mine is even faster. With 57083 data, mine takes 19 secs and yours around 22 secs

Comment: @Elana Please try [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/s1ccWxq84). It runs significantly faster on random data (`size=10000, Runtime(your method)=114 ms, Runtime(new algorithm)=4 ms` ) If it is OK for your real data, I will explain it in the answer.

Comment: Ok I understand your code and it is veery efficient, but I have one last doubt. I need to fill a file only with those non-overlapping spheres. How could I do it? Because I don't know how to access the index

Comment: The `new_algorithm` function sets `overlaps` array (to indicate overlapping spheres) and you have to process it exactly the same way you would do using your own code.

Comment: Ok I understand. I've done many probes and it works perfectly! You have saved my life, thanks for the help

Comment: If you find it useful do not forget to upvote answers useful for you, and accept one of the answers.

Comment: I can't vote because I don't have enough reputation, but if I could I would do it

Comment: Hey there, I have one more question. How could I edit the code if I the problem is the following one? I have several spheres and I want to order them in decreasing order. I start with the first one and check if it overlaps with others... if it does I delete the bigger one and keep going on this way with all these spheres. This time I only delete the bigger sphere.

Comment: Decreasing order of what? its radius?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I used the same code but making some changes, like ordering the spheres in decreasing order this way:  std::sort(S.begin(), S.end(), [](sphere const&a, sphere const&b) { return a.R > b.R; });
and "deleting" the bigger ones that overlaps with others this way:  for(size_t i=0; i<S.size(); ++i) 
 {
  for(size_t j=i+1; j<S.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (overlap(S[i], S[j]))
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                overlaps[S[i].index] = 1;
            }
            if(overlaps[S[i].index]==1) break;
        }
    }

Comment: but it's not efficient enough because the second loop is too long

Comment: Well, it is a different algorithm, which gives different result. Unfortunately, It will not be as efficient as sorting by x, because you lost the advantage of examining those x values only that are closer than twice the largest radius. I will add a slightly faster code to my answer soon.

Comment: I think I may be making some mistakes on filling a file only with non overlapping spheres. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let us first improve your serial code a bit by avoiding to loop over already deleted spheres:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
    if(r[i]>0) {
        for(size_t j=i+1; j<r.size(); ++j)
            if(r[j]>0 && (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j])
                       + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j])
                       + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])
                       < (r[i]+r[j])*(r[i]+r[j]) ) {
                r[j] = 0;
                r[i] = 0;
            }            
    }
```

This immediately shows you that the execution of the outer loop depends on all previous executions at smaller index, since these may have removed some of the spheres. This interdependence of the loop executions implies that your algorithm cannot be straightforwardly parallelized (in the way you attempted it).

Also, you have race conditions in the variables `r[]`, which are read and written to. Your naive parallelization didn't take care of that problem either.

Comment: there isn't another different way of writting the code in order to parallelize it? I need to run it with r.size()=33.000.000 aprox and without parallelization it can take days to run

Comment: and how could i fix the problem about three overlapping spheres? because there would be one without being deleted, right?

Comment: I would suggest to apply something around the lines of a "merge sort": divide all the circles into relatively small groups so you can check them in parallel, then put together the circles which don't overlap. Repeat the operation, until there are no overlaps...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still interested, I've improved my code and now it's more efficient (althought now enough for me yet) and now it does eliminate overlapping spheres:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
    {
        overlaps[i]=0;
    }
    cout << "overlaps igualados a cero..." << endl;

    //Me queda ver qué esferas se superponen y eliminarlas. Primero voy a ver comprobar qué esferas se superponen y posteriormente hago el radio de aquellas
    //que se superponen igual a cero.
    double cero = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {   
        contador=0;
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:contador)
        for (j = i + 1; j < r.size(); j++)
        {
                if ((((xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j])) < (r[i] + r[j]) * (r[i] + r[j])))
                {
                    contador++;
                    overlaps[i] = contador;
                    overlaps[j]=contador;
                }
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
    {
        if(overlaps[i]!=0)
        {
            r[i]=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code will not calculate the number of overlaps properly, but since you do not use the exact number it is not a problem. I suggest using `overlaps[i]=1; overlaps[j]= 1;` and remove variable `contador`. Note also that it is still possible to increase the speed of your program.

Comment: @Laci I know I don't calculate the number of overlaps but honestly I don't mind as I don't need it. If I remove variable contador I get problems with         #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:contador) and openmp. How could I increase the speed of my program? I'm suffering and I need to run in with vectors of dimension similar to 30.000.000

Comment: Are you allowed to sort your vectors? How many spheres removed in a typical run? 1% or half of them? Can you use `struct sphere { double r,x,y,z; };` to store all data together or does it require too many changes in your program, so you prefer not to use this structure?

Comment: @Laci Usuarlly more than the half are removed in a typical run